# Webview loading url but opening content in default browser?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-developer-api

It opens my link in Webview but when I try to open hyperlinks and content of the web or navigation link, it starts opening with the default browser.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);


        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


         mWebView.loadUrl("http://");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(Uri.parse(url).getHost()).endsWith("http://www.ieltsmadeeasy.tk/")) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

}

I want to browse the whole website inside the web view, not any browser please help me

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation about WebViews: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java

The problem is, that you don't override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)` function of the WebViewClient, as you use the default one.

If you use this as the WebViewClient, it should work (copied from examples in documentation):

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://www.example.com")) {
            // This is my website, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, just take this class and change the line `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` to `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());`

Comment: thx for the reply but this did not work for I tried and sorry I forgot to mention about this code even though didn't work

Comment: You call ```endsWith()```, I think, you should call ```Objects.requireNonNull(Uri.parse(url).getHost()).startsWith("http://www.ieltsmadeeasy.tk")```. Try to System.out.println(), what ```Objects.requireNonNull(Uri.parse(url).getHost())``` returns and use that as a "inspiration"

Comment: Very nice to hear. Glad, I could help